# Change photo in Panorama run time

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Panorama control
xaml layout is :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <controls:Panorama Title="my application">  v
         <!--Assigns a background image to the Panorama control.-->
         <controls:Panorama.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="samplePhoto.jpg"/>
         </controls:Panorama.Background>
               <!--Panorama item one-->
               <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
                <Grid/>
               </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

How i can change image samplePhoto.jpg in c#?
thank

Answer (score 3):

A snippet like this will do the trick:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("IMAGE_URI",UriKind.Absolute));

ImageBrush b = new ImageBrush();
b.ImageSource = image;

<PANORAMA_CONTROL>.Background = b;
```

BitmapImage is able to download online images too, so if there is an image that is available through a web site/service, you can pass the URL to it directly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good post by *Jeff Wilcox* to that shows how to do that:

[WP7 Panorama: Smoothly fading the background (and enabling fading when changing, too)](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/11/wp7-panorama-smooth-background-changing/)