# Convert address to coordinates

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, bing-maps

There is a way to convert address to coordinates with  bing maps?

Thank

Comment: To help other users who have the same questions as you, then it helps if you can make answers as accepted - e.g. were any of the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212811/stringformat-in-wp7 accepted? or to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209275/change-photo-in-panorama-run-time?

Answer (score 5):

The process of going from addresses to lat/lng coordinates is normally called **Geocoding**

This blog post has some good example code for WP7 using Bing - http://www.braincastexception.com/wp7-web-services-first-part-geocodeservice/