# how to convert address box text to geo long lat. in wp7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I want to convert my address box text into Geo coordinates so i can put pin on map. here is the xaml code of my map.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

        <my:Map Height="683" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CredentialsProvider="bingmapcode" Margin="0,0,0,13" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460"/>

</Grid>
```

i have my address saved in string type variable. How can i convert it to coordinates.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529135/convert-address-to-coordinates

Comment: All of them using there web service to retrive long and lat. I want to get long and lat from address text box. for example someone write newyork in address box the map will go to new york after clicking on it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code I adapted a while back from MSDN.  Add a address textbox, and Find button to search the map.

```
<TextBox Height="23" Name="txt_address" Width="84" />
<Button Content="Find" Height="23" Margin="0 0 5 0"  Name="btn_Find"  Width="64" Click="btn_Find_Click"   />
```

Button click event;

```
private void btn_Find_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
FindAndDisplayNearbyPOI(Geocode(txt_address.Text));
}

   public XmlDocument Geocode(string addressQuery)
    {
        string BingMapsKey = "You bing key";
        string geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/" + addressQuery + "?o=xml&key=" + BingMapsKey;

        XmlDocument geocodeResponse = GetXmlResponse(geocodeRequest);

        return geocodeResponse;
    }

    private XmlDocument GetXmlResponse(string requestURL)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                    response.StatusCode,
                    response.StatusDescription));
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

            return xmlDoc;
        }
    }

private Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location FindAndDisplayNearbyPOI(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
        {
            Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location();
            // Create namespace manager
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("rest", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");

            // Get all locations in the response and then extract the coordinates for the top location
            XmlNodeList locationElements = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//rest:Location", nsmgr);

            if (locationElements.Count == 0)
            {
                //ErrorMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                //ErrorMessage.Content = "The location you entered could not be geocoded.";
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the geocode points that are used for display (UsageType=Display)
                XmlNodeList displayGeocodePoints = locationElements[0].SelectNodes(".//rest:GeocodePoint/rest:UsageType[.='Display']/parent::node()", nsmgr);
                string latitude = displayGeocodePoints[0].SelectSingleNode(".//rest:Latitude", nsmgr).InnerText;
                string longitude = displayGeocodePoints[0].SelectSingleNode(".//rest:Longitude", nsmgr).InnerText;

                pushpin = AddPushpinToMap(Convert.ToDouble(latitude), Convert.ToDouble(longitude), "Cust");

                map1.Center = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(Convert.ToDouble(latitude), Convert.ToDouble(longitude));
                map1.ZoomLevel = 12;
            }

            return pushpin;
        }

private Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location AddPushpinToMap(double latitude, double longitude, string pinLabel)
{

    Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location location = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(latitude, longitude);
    Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin();
    pushpin.Content = pinLabel;
    pushpin.Location = location;


    map1.Children.Add(pushpin);

    return pushpin.Location;
}
```